# Session Time Out

Tags: asp.net, session

We are developing a web application in Asp.net(4.0). In this application we use jquery and javascript and webservices and I frames

Here I am getting  the problem with session expire. How can I solve this? I can't understand where the session is expiring.

Comment: Session by default expires after 20minutes in Asp.Net application. So you must handle it in your app. Explain what you want or specify where you need that

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question properly, you can adjust session timeout in your Web.config file, using something like this:

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState mode="[Off|InProc|StateServer|SQLServer|Custom]" timeout="[numberOfMinutes]" />
  ...
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of JQuery, javascript, webservices, and IFrames are not affecting your session expiration issue.

The following page is an excellent resource for learning to use the Session State:

[ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

Go to the section on that page titled **Configuring Session State** for information pertaining specifically to your question.

**Here's your options for Session State configuration, including timeout:**

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer"
  cookieless="true "
  regenerateExpiredSessionId="true "
  timeout="30"
  sqlConnectionString="Data Source=MySqlServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
  stateNetworkTimeout="30"/>
```